# Spider Solitaire Puzzle - Can You Help Joe Bloggs Achieve His Goal?

Tags: story, cards, sliding-blocks

It was yet another dreary Friday afternoon. Hardly anybody to talk to and the internet connection was flaky as usual. And the less said about his latest performance review the better. Hardly anything to look at either, except for this dreaded “demotivational poster” hanging on the wall. Apparently, the boss only got ‘C’ in Year 10 art.
[image]

Yesterday Joe Bloggs had a clever thought. Suppose he could remove the apostrophe and the happystar. Then he could treat the black letters as part of a 4x4 sliding block puzzle. With a bit of luck he could rearrange these letters to spell a much more positive message. But try as he might, when Joe experimented with a set of Scrabble tiles the best he could achieve was **DEAD PIGS FLY TONW**. At least the poster didn’t mention anything about procrastination.

Joe stared at his computer screen. Not the most promising game state, but he had seen worse. At least he had one empty column and had turned over most of the cards in the tableau. It would be tempting to reveal another face-down card in column 8 but at this point in the game Joe desperately needed to complete a full suit.

[image]

Perhaps Joe could increase his chances ever so slightly if he could swap the J-0-9-8-7-6-5-4-3 in column 1 with the J-0-9 in column 2. Then he would have a run of three cards, K-Q-J in Spades. Together with the length-7 straight flush in Spades in Column 6, he might get lucky enough to complete Spades after dealing the final round from the stock. Not much, but better than nothing. After scanning for other possibilities he found nothing better. **The goal was decided: Obtain K-Q-J of Spades in column 1, then turnover a card in column 8.**

Questions:

(1) How Can Joe Bloggs achieve his goal?

(2) What is the significance of the sliding block puzzle in the above story?

*Note: it is assumed the reader knows the rules of Spider Solitaire since this information is easily found online.*

**Text format of current game state (? = face-down card):**

????? 9h 8h 7c 6c 5c 4c 3s 2s As Jd Qc Jd Ks Qs Jc 0c 9c 8c 7h 6h 5h 4h 3h

? 9d 8c 7s 6s 5h Js 4s Kd Qs Js 0h 9h

8d 7d 6d 5d 4d 3d 2d Ad Ac

4h 7c

Ah

Kh Qh Jh 0d 9d 8d 7d Kc Qc Jc 0c 9s 8s 7s 6s 5s 4s 3s

Kd

?? 4d 3d 2d Ad 6d

2c Ac Kh Qh Jh 0h 9s 8s 7h 6h 5d 4c 3c 2c Ah

empty-column

Stock = 10

Checksum: 28+13+9+2+1+18+1+7+15+0+(1x10) = 104

**Text format of sliding block puzzle:**

Row 1 = D, E, A, D

Row 2 = P, I, G, S

Row 3 = W, O, N, T

Row 4 = F, L, Y, blank

Comment: The two D's in the sliding block puzzle mean that all arrangements of the letters are accessible.  I am guessing that one of the top corner squares finishes with a D but it must be the other one.  I don't know how that helps the spider.

Comment: Ross Millikan, yes that is correct. Now onto the spider!

Comment: Do you know if there's a way to get the spider solitaire state into a better screenshot? or better yet, an interactive version :)